# Can I control positioning of IE 10 select boxes?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

In Internet Explorer 10 the behavior of drop-down boxes (`<select>` element) has changed: when expanding the box, instead of placing the list of options below the field, the list overlays the field, with the list positioned so that the currently-selected element is centered over the input field.

This is a little hard to describe, [so here's a jsFiddle that shows it](http://jsfiddle.net/KnAXL/).

Our users are finding this behavior very confusing. Is there anything I can do in CSS to make the box behave like it did in IE9, and like every other major browser? (Perhaps something like the [-ms-clear pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs) that hides the clear button in IE10 text input fields.)

Here's a sort of time-lapse screenshot:

[image: IE 10 select box behavior screenshot]

Comment: My IE10 is not experiencing that behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select drop-down list possible to "Drop-Up"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919573/select-drop-down-list-possible-to-drop-up)

Comment: Unless MS implemented something similar to `-webkit-appearance` which I bet not, you can always use a hidden `<select>` and implement one in JS, like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) (which then support search, etc). On side note, try use `select::-ms-expand {/*stuff*/}` to style the arrow and `select::-ms-value {/*stuff*/}` for the value part, maybe you can try force it, those pseudo-elements are available to style selects on IE

Comment: @Diodeus this is not a duplicate of that question. the other question is talking about controlling location of option box in general. i'm asking if there is any IE-specific modification, similar to -ms-clear for text inputs.

Answer (score -1):

One option is dynamically change `size` property of the select to the number of options (or a fixed number - if you have too many options). You would do it on mouse-down, and change it back on-change.

Style, Position of select as well as additional events will have to be tweaked - but here is the proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/KnAXL/1/

Comment: not working for me--when i select "the", then the next time I click it, it goes back to the first item in the list without expanding the list.

Comment: Yup. IE10 looks like IE10 completely rewrote the behavior and this workaround no longer works. Reason being - IE10 displays full list always relative to selected option. Here's an explanation and possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18329113/961695