# Select list does not work properly under IE

Tags: html, angularjs, select

Tested with IE 11.

html:

```
<div data-ng-app="testApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <select id="filter" ng-model="messageViewModel.filter" ng-options="f.name for f in messageViewModel.filters"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.messageViewModel = {};
    $scope.messageViewModel.filters = [{ id:1, name: "test1"}, { id:2, name: "test2"}, { id:3, name: "test3"}];
    $scope.messageViewModel.filter = $scope.messageViewModel.filters[0];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u69PT/28/

Steps:

1. Select an option from the select list
2. The option is selected. Then try to select another option.

Result: the select list is opened "upwards".

Any ideas ? I am not sure that it is related but I am using angularjs to populate the select list.

Comment: I think this is related to default IE behavior with select element (tested it without angular.js). Not helpful, but... maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056593/can-i-control-positioning-of-ie-10-select-boxes

Answer (score 0):

This is just the default behaviour of Internet Explorer. It keeps the selected option level with the select box. 
This means as you progress further down the select list the drop down starts to move upwards when opened.

I believe its been doing it since IE 10.