# How to remove clear button ( 'X' button ) from IE10 textboxes in compatibility mode?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Currently I am working on a website which is using meta tag to render the page in IE9 mode  [  BrowserMode: IE10, DocMode: IE9 Standards ]

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7, IE=9" />
```

In IE10 lots of CSS breaks in the page, so using `IE=Edge` is not a viable solution as of now ( may be in future this will be used once all the css is fixed, but I don't see this near future ).

Now, the point is all of the textbox have clear button in it. In just one of the textbox we don't need that cross ( as we already have a custom (x) button far right from text-box ).

I tried `::-ms-clear` but that didn;t worked as we are on BrowserMode: IE10 and DocMode:Standards.  What can be done now to remove that 'X' .

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196845/ie-10s-ms-clear-pseudo-element-and-ie5-quirks-mode except that one asks about IE5 Quirks and not Compatibility View. Obviously, `::-ms-clear` won't work in either mode.

Comment: @BoltClock Could you please suggest what can I do here? Also, is there any website where we can suggest feature request to MsIE to give some option to remove 'X' when DocMode is < 10 ( though I really doubt it :D )  In my case BrowserMode is IE10 but DocMode is IE9.

Comment: [Identical question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050416/disable-ie10-clear-field-in-compatibility-mode#comment29865337_20050416). Again, the short answer is that you just can't do this. It isn't possible. If you really want to be rid of this widget, then your **only** option is to use standards mode. If that means fixing your broken CSS to get it working, then maybe that's a good thing.

Comment: Re suggesting the feature: The question I just linked above has a link to MS connect, where you can ask the question. But don't expect it to happen in IE10 or IE11 because they've already been released, and I can't see them adding new functionality post-release. So whatever happens in the future, you're going to have to deal with it in IE10 and IE11.

Comment: I don't understand, why you dislike this feature in IE10.  Similarly  there is [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18313867/1671639) for select tag in IE10.  In my opinion it is really good otherwise you can go with plugins like bootstrap, etc.,

Comment: @Praveen Jeganathan: He said "we already have a custom (x) button far right from text-box"

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan we don't dislike this feature, we just don't need it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Since @Spudley mentioned that not possible *my question, do you think it is better to hide the 'X' `button far right from text-box` only in IE10?*  which is possible using conditional comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this issue. Apparently if you set `height` and `line-height` to 0 and `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to half of the height of your textbox, then this awesome **'X'** will not be displayed anymore.  Atleast this worked for me.

Here is the code pen:
http://codepen.io/rjuyal/pen/iGKnI

**Excerpt from code**

```
.gen{
                margin: 10px;
                margin-top: 40px;

                box-shadow: inset 1px 2p 0 rgba(200, 100,10, 0.2 );
                font-size: 16px;

                width: 400px;
                line-height: 18px;
                height:  41px;
                fint-family: 'Lucida Grande' , 'Arial';
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .ie10f{
                height: 0px !important;
                line-height: 0px !important;
                padding-top: 22px !important;
                padding-bottom: 22px !important;
            }
```

You will see two text-boxes one with **X**  another without it.
Best part is, this hides **X** in IE10 ( no compatibility mode ) also.

P.S.  You will have to manually change the DocMode to IE9  from developer tools.

Comment: For some reason using IE9 mode it doesn't work, and on IE8 it works, but it looks so weird. What I needed really was for <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8" /> setting height:0; padding:10px; was enough for me to make it look as it was with the "x" (only without showing the "x"). Thanks for helping explore an alternate solution.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but this is not possible.

If you want to get rid of the close widget, your **only** option is to switch to standards mode.

> In IE10 lots of CSS breaks in the page, so using `IE=Edge` is not a viable solution as of now ( may be in future this will be used once all the css is fixed, but I don't see this near future ).

So I guess it comes down to how badly you want to get rid of the `X` widget. If it's bugging you that badly then you will have to bite the bullet, fix your CSS, and switch to standards mode.

Otherwise, you'll just have to live it.

Sorry.

Comment: **I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news**, how dramatic ;) +1 for it

Comment: I feel uneasy about closing the other question as a dupe of this one since they differ by less than a day. Why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: Thanks, I found this:  http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783743/disable-ie10-clear-field-button-when-rendering-in-compatibility-mode   **Microsoft** says this is by design.

Comment: @BoltClock - I couldn't vote for a dup, since neither of the other questions had an accepted answer. Otherwise I would have done.

Comment: @BoltClock I have found the solution ( atleast it is working for me ). I will post it soon.

Comment: @Spudley I have posted the fix for it. It is working in *IE10* with DocMode as *IE9*.