# Internet Explorer 10 ::-ms-clear within compatibility mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to hide the input clear button within IE10 when it is in compatibility mode.

I have used this:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear, input[type=text]::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
}
```

This works for IE10 Standards mode but not compatibility mode.

Any ideas how i can do this? Is there any way to disable it using JavaScript?

Comment: I am in the same position.  I need a fix for IE10 and IE11 when in Compatibility mode.  There is a bug filed that the IE Team has responded as won't fix: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783743/disable-ie10-clear-field-button-when-rendering-in-compatibility-mode

Comment: any progress on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this isn't the answer you are perhaps looking for but Microsoft have said that this is "by design" and "is a feature" of the browser and will not fix it.

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783743/disable-ie10-clear-field-button-when-rendering-in-compatibility-mode

> The product team believes this item works according to its intended
>   design.

Some people have tried setting `line-height: 0; height: 0; padding: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;` with some degree of success as per the following post:

[How to remove clear button ( 'X' button ) from IE10 textboxes in compatibility mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068256/how-to-remove-clear-button-x-button-from-ie10-textboxes-in-compatibility-m)

Comment: Another tick on the list of "why I hate Microsoft".